# How to use an extended class to create an instance?

Tags: java, oop

I am trying to use an extended class to create an instance however I'm a little confused.

It's very hard for me to explain this sort of stuff but here is what I am trying to do:

I have test1.java which contains

```
private double value1;
private double value2;
private double value3;
```

and getters and setters for all of them.

I have test2.java which extends test1.java.

I have a new value

```
private double value4;
```

In test2.java I also have a constructor with the following inside of it

```
test1 t = new test1();
t.setValue3(5.5);
```

I also have a setter and a getter for the new value4.

Now finally I have my third class, test3.java

I want to create a few instances using this however I have no idea how to use the test2.java.

All I know is I can make an instance with test1.java but how do I also include test2.java stuff so that every instance will have value3 of 5.5 and will also include the value4?

Comment: There is no need to explicitly "create" a `test1` instance inside the constructor of `test2`.

Comment: You should start your class names with capital letters

Comment: @manouti I want to use the `value4` in `test2` (and have `value3` set to 5.5) whilst also using everything in `test1`. How do I create this instance in `test3`? That's what I'm basically asking.

@steven35 It's just an example

Comment: Sorry totally misread your comment @manouti. Where should I create it? (Or how else should I set that value?)

Comment: Ah nevermind, I see what you mean. Thanks for the tip! :)

Comment: " I have no idea how to use the test2.java"; I don't think you generally have an idea at all about Java's inheritance mechanism nor object orientated analysis and design. You need to read thoroughly the widely available literature that is available *freely* on the internet and then maybe ask specific and reasonable questions afterwards. Your question indicates a gross breakdown in understanding in the aforementioned areas.

Comment: @I.K. If I knew how to word my problem I would explain it. Instead of being useless and referring me to other places you should of just ignored the question :)

Comment: There is no need to be defensive. Good programming is about understanding: understanding the problem domain and understanding the tool to solve the problem. Your previous comment and your post indicate a breakdown in both those areas. SO is not a medium to solve that type problem. SO is for solving *well specified* problems.

Comment: @I.K. Sorry, I was just trying to get someone else to take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `test2.java`  extends `test1.java` ,So all the  `public/protected` members(to be specific getters and setters ) are inherited in `test2.java`

Now in `test3.java` you have to just do this

- Create Object of Class `test2.java` (say test2)

Now Call as many getters and setters you want to call .

```
test2.getValue1();
test2.getValue2();
test2.getValue3();
test2.setValue4(2.2);
```

and In constructor of `test2.java` you can directly call , `setValue3(2.5)` instead of creating new Object of class `test1.java`

> every instance will have value3 of 5.5

Yes Now whenever you create Object of class `test2.java` you will get `value3 as 5.5`

Answer (score 0):

If `Test3 extends Test2` it will have the value `value4`.Regarding costructors your line in `Test2`'s costructor

```
test1 t=new test1();
```

create a new object `Test1` inside your `Test2` object.I think you wanted to set your inherited variables in your `Test2`, to do so rewrite the costructor as:

```
super();
this.setValue3(5.5);
```

The function `super()` call the superclass constructor and the keyword `this` refers to the class it's used.So in the new class `Test3` just do the same thing in its constructor to have the `value3` setted to 5.5

Comment: **Private Members** are not inherited !! So `Test3` will not have `value4`